# keyof result contains 'undefined' when used on object mapped from object with optional keys

Tags: typescript

How is this possible? AFAIK `undefined` can't be used as an object key. And `FooOptionalNumber` doesn't contain such a key. Where did it come from? Does TS add `undefined` to objects under some conditions?

```
type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = Pick<T, {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never;
}[keyof T]>;

interface Foo {
    user: string

    age?: number
    score?: number    
}

//'user' | 'age' | 'score' - as expected
type FooKeys = keyof Foo

// as exptected
// { 
//     age?: number | undefined
//     score?: number | undefined
// }
type FooOptionalNumber = PickByValue<Foo, number | undefined>

// 'age' | 'score' | undefined - Where did the 'undefined' come from??
type FooOptionalNumberKeys = keyof FooOptionalNumber
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBACglgYwNYCEQDUCGAbArhAHgBUAaKLPCI8CAPigF5ZEliyBvAKCh6gG0A0hBBQ4AOyhJhAewBmUIgF0AXAsHDFUCAA9gEMQBMAzuRz5qkKAH4oQkarEQAbhABOAbk4BfPlJByFRVpPTnE9V1lMBGgAMWlpKC5eKFwjN1UjYFdxAHNObl5MHIgrB1wAWwAjNwKeIwRpVxKyqrdk73yAek6AclS3HqgAHygeoohBkZ76xomoAFooTBMdSAQ9A05QSzjpOxMmPwDdrs6lle0wPXWITe7EqE575PHSqDEK6tdhlMMIWXEtyeZ2SMyabw+rW+I1wfwBjjuZy8WxoUF2AHkrnBpGIcAA5T5tJjwZBoCj4Ai7MiQr4-WEGf6Agy0U6jcaTUZguYwuFMhZQADqAAs3NADHADFBgCLRvTGQjBg1ytBZK5pOUrFYUTt4pjgNjcdgCVD9oxJDJ5BisTj8YTXEA)

Comment: "Where did the 'undefined' come from??" -> The `?` in `age` or `score`.

Comment: i don`t see undefined. maybe problem with your ide.

Comment: @yantrab did you visit my link to TS playground? I encountered the issue both in there and in my vscode

Comment: @Caramiriel if `?` adds `undefined` to `keyof` result, then why no `undefined` in `keyof Foo`?

Comment: An object literal can be written like `let o = {undefined: 42}`, but only because undefined is coerced as "undefined" string key. Your case actually seems to be buggy - to my knowledge one can't have a `undefined` (non-string) typed key which TS reports with `FooOptionalNumberKeys` type. In the Playground, one can even write `type T1 = Pick<FooOptionalNumber, "age" | undefined>`, whereas `type T2 = Pick<Foo, "age" | undefined>` correctly emits an error. I could imagine `type FooOptionalNumber = PickByValue<Foo, number | undefined>` to compile, as type resolution is deferred in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript expert answer is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34992).
This definition

```
type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = Pick<T, {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never;
}[keyof T]>;
```

is invalid and should actually give a compile error(but it doesn't). This is because optional properties of type `never` actually become `undefined`:

```
type SpecialUndefined = { foo?: never } //actually it is: { foo?: undefined }
```

So this expression `{ [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends ValueType ? Key : never;}` makes optional values not extending `ValueType` to be `undefined` instead of `never`. Therefore the union we pass to `Pick` as the second argument contains `undefined` -  `Pick<User, "foo" | undefined>`. Applying `keyof` to this type just pulls out the supplied key `"foo" | undefined` - despite the fact that this is an illegal type to begin with.

Comment: It looks like `PickByValue` comes from [this utility library](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#pickbyvaluet-valuetype).  If I understand correctly, @vatosarmat fixed this issue by removing optionality from the mapped type (using `-?`).